# Passing a string from an activity to a broadcast receiver

Tags: android, string, broadcastreceiver

I am having a problem while passing a string from my main activity to my broadcast receiver when the app is not currently open on the screen.

When the MainActivity class is created the intent filter returns the correct information through the broadcast receiver but as soon as the user goes to the homescreen on their phone the broadcast receiver starts returning "null" for the toast when the receiver is triggered offscreen.

**1.** New Intent

```
Intent home_page = new Intent(newIntent.this,MainActivity.class);

 ownAddress  = ""+customInput.getText().toString();
  home_page.putExtra("session_number", ""+ownAddress);

startActivity(home_page);
```

**2.** MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {
SmsReceiver mAppReceiver = new SmsReceiver();

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    final String ownAddress  = bundle.getString("session_number");

    registerReceiver(mAppReceiver, new IntentFilter("SmsReceiver"));
     Intent intent = new Intent("SmsReceiver");
      intent.putExtra("passAddress", ownAddress);
    sendBroadcast(intent);

 }

}
```

**3.** SmsReceiver.java:

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Toast showme = Toast.makeText(context,"Number: "+intent.getExtras().get("passAddress"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    showme.show();

 }

}
```

Is there anyway to pass the string through to the broadcast receiver while the app is only running in the background or regardless of when the MainActivity class is created?

Comment: An `Activity` is effectively a UI framework. If it's not visible then, in general terms, it's not running. Explain more about what you're trying to do, it's not clear.

Comment: I need to have a string passed from the activity to the broadcast receiver every time that it is triggered because the app that I am building will then perform an HttpPost based off of the content of the string.

Comment: I still don't understand - an `Activity` shouldn't be 'triggered' by 'events' that's the whole point of `BroadcastReceivers`. What is 'triggering' the `Activity` - it seems to me you need to by-pass the 'middle-man' (the `Activity`) because you can't guarantee that it will always be running as your question obviously is all about. An `Activity` is a UI framework - it's not a general purpose class.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong here but, logically, the reason why "the broadcast receiver starts returning "null" for the toast when the receiver is triggered offscreen" is because the context that you pass to the onReceive constructor is destroyed when the user goes to the homescreen.

I guess one solution for passing the string would be to create a public static string variable in MainActivity which is used to store the string value you want to pass. Then all you have to do is access this string statically in your BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: **"...create a public static string variable in MainActivity..."** Please don't advise this for an Android `Activity`. Any class which extends `Activity` should never expose `static` variables or methods.

Comment: @Squonk Oh, I didn't know that! I'm curious, why shouldn't we do that?

Comment: @VishwaPatel : The `Activity` class isn't just any ordinary Java class. It's one of the fundamental components of Android and should be treated as a special case. An `Activity` should only ever be started through the 'launcher' process or by another Android component using `startActivity(...)` or one of the other similar methods. Attempting to expose `static` variables or methods on a class which extends `Activity` will fail.

Comment: @Squonk thanks for your reply. I'm still trying to understand in what cases would exposing a static String variable (or a static Bitmap, as I'm using a static Bitmap in a small personal project) fail? Could you provide an example?

Comment: @VishwaPatel : OK, perhaps to use the words *will fail* is extreme. My point is that an Android dev should not take the approach of using `static` variables or methods in an `Activity` and expect to be able to use them from other app components. The life-cycle of an `Activity` is often indeterminate and an `Activity` should be self-contained. It goes against Android design fundamentals to use an `Activity` as a place-holder for anything `static`. Using helper classes or even extending `Application` to maintain global state are much more robust.